# Change X axsis scale in R

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, forecasting

I have data which is monthly, but it displays as two year intervals. I wish for this to be displayed as monthly. [image: Plot shown, see x axsis]

I plotted using GGfortify and ggplot 2 using the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggfortify)
spendingARIMA <- arima(spendingSaas, order = c(2, 1, 0))
fianlforecastSpending <- forecast(spendingARIMA, h= 6, level = 30) 
autoplot(fianlforecastSpending)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
dates <- seq(as.POSIXct("2016-1-1"), as.POSIXct("2018-1-1"), by="month") # make dates
df <- data.frame(dates = dates, value = rnorm(25)) # make data frame

ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y=value)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "month") + #This is the key line
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle = -90, hjust = 1, vjust=.3)) #rotate x-axis 90 deg.
```